# RNCryptor in C# and Swift, RNCryptorError error 2

Tags: c#, swift, encryption, aes, rncryptor

I am using RNCryptor in Swift and C#.NET . I need a cross platform AES encryption and because of this, I am using RNCryptor.
When I encrypt some plain text in Swift,I can decrypt it in Swift correctly without any error. But when I encrypt some text in C# and then I want to decrypt it in Swift,I got an error " The operation couldn’t be completed. (RNCryptorError error 2.)"

My code in C# :

```
public static string EncryptQRCode(string qrCodeString){
        var qrEncryptor = new Encryptor ();
    return  qrEncryptor.Encrypt (qrCodeString, "password");

    }
public static string DecryptQRCode(string qrEncryptedString){
        var qrDecryptor = new Decryptor();
      return qrDecryptor.Decrypt (qrEncryptedString, "password");
    }
```

My Code in Swift:

```
func Encrypt(msg:String, pwd:String) -> String{
    let data = msg.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding,      allowLossyConversion: false)
    let chiper = RNCryptor.encryptData(data!, password: pwd)
    let base = chiper.base64EncodedDataWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    let stringBase = String(data: base, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    return stringBase!
}
func Decrypt(msg:String, pwd:String) -> String{
    let encodedData:NSData = NSData(base64EncodedString: msg, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))!
    do{
        let decryptedData = try RNCryptor.decryptData(encodedData, password: pwd)
        let decrypytedString = String(data: text, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        return decryptedString!
    }
    catch let error as NSError{
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        
    }
    return "AN ERROR OCCURED"

}
```

For example:

"ABC", with password "behdad" in C#, Encryptor returned:

> "AgHfT2VvVOorlux0Ms47K46fG5lQOP2YhYWq2KeIKh+MisCDqZfrLF+KsJyBR2EBNC3wQpaKev0X4+9uuC5vliVoHkLsEi6ZI7ZIZ8qVUEkYGQ=="

When I decrypt it in C#, it returned "ABC".

But when I pass this Base64Encoded string to my Swift Decryptor function,it returned:

> RNCryptorError error 2.

For Example:
qrCodeString = "ABC".
public static string EncryptQRCode returns =

> "AgF6P5Ya0SifSymd3LqKdH+kGMCFobiziUhwwB6/lfZgAA9N+F5h350MyigoKo9qgUpMXX3x9FxZXwUOJODL4is3R62EGvZWdJBzjSNCef7Ouw=="

The "msg" is returned data from EncryptQRCode(The Base64 Encoded String).

> pwd = "password"
>
> encoded data = <02017a3f 961ad128 9f4b299d dcba8a74 7fa418c0 85a1b8b3 894870c0 1ebf95f6 60000f4d f85e61df 9d0cca28 282a8f6a 814a4c5d 7df1f45c 595f050e 24e0cbe2 2b3747ad 841af656 7490738d 234279fe cebb>

decryptedString and decryptedData do not have values due to the error occurred.

Comment: What have you done to debug? Dump the data and passwords just prior to and just after encryption and decryption. Compare to determine where the problem exists. Add that to the question.

Comment: Thank you,I edited the question. @zaph

Comment: Is it possible that Base64Encoding algorithm of C# differ from Base64Encoding in Swift? @zaph

Comment: Check the Base64 [documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), the standard encoding consists of the characters "a-zA-Z0-9+/=".

Comment: I want to know exactly what is returned by `qrEncryptor.Encrypt (qrCodeString, "password");` and `msg` sent to `Decrypt(msg:String`, and `encodedData` in hex and `pwd` and `text` in hex and `k`. In other words the data at each stage. Also upgrade variable names, it help if they are descriptive, `k` isn't.

Comment: I change "k" to "decryptedString". Im sorry for bad variable name.

Comment: I change "text" to "decryptedData".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C# when you want to encrypt the text,you have to use Schema.V3 for encryption. Decryptor in Swift cannot identify the Schema Version of Base 64 encoded string.

```
string encrypted = encryptor.Encrypt (YOUR_PLAIN_TEXT, YOUR_PASSWORD,Schema.V3);
```

Answer (score 1):

RNCryptorError error 2

> UnknownHeader = 2
>   Unrecognized data format. Usually this means the data is corrupt.

This means that the data passed is not in the correct format.

The best programming advice I ever got was one night in the computer room when I asked Rick Cullman for help and he said: "Read the documentation."

That is why I suggested displaying the inputs and outputs, you will catch that.

There are many places where hexadecimal is need to see what is happening and to debug.

Opened an [issue](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor/issues/193) in RNCryptor Swift to add the error codes to the documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. The  "-initWithBase64EncodedString:options:" is in Obj C as you know. In Swift that is: "NSData(base64EncodedString: source,  options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))" . The same code that I wrote for "func Decrypt". And It returns me a NSData object that initialized with the give Base64 Encoded String. And Also when I try my Encrypt and Decrypt func in Swift,It works Correct. But with a Base64 Encoded string from another language,it return an error. Again,Thank you so much for helping me! @zaph